# How to get array of byte when wsdl file is generetion?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Part of wsdl:

```
<complexType name="Example">
                    <sequence>
                        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="base64bytes" type="xsd:byte"/>
                        <element name="fileName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
```

After generation with jaxws-maven-plugin intellijIDEA:

```
@XmlElement(name = "base64bytes", type = Byte.class)
    protected List<Byte> base64Bytes;
```

How i should change my wsdl file or ws that i get array of bytes instead List of Bytes after generation ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

[xsd:base64Binary](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_base64Binary.html)

instead of `xsd:byte`.
The type `xsd:base64Binary` represents binary data as a sequence of binary octets and so it will be generated as a byte Array.

Moreover you should delete the `maxOccurs="unbounded"`, because this attribute generate a List of byte array.

Comment: with this deal its retutn     
                      @XmlElement(name = "base64bytes")
                       protected List<byte[]> base64Bytes;

Comment: I think that you don't need maxOccurs="unbounded" attribute and you should delete it.